# WebSocket connection to <AWS IoT Url> failed: EMPTY

Tags: typescript, mqtt, iot, aws-iot, mqtt.js

I am working with this library for my AWS IoT MQTT topics. However, I've run into an issue when trying to connect to the  presigned-url of the following format:

`wss://<endpoint>.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mqtt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=<credential>%2Fus-west-2%2Fiotdevicegateway%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=<date>&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=<signature>&X-Amz-Security-Token=<security-token>`

Here is the sample code I've used for this test:

```
import * as mqtt from 'mqtt';

try {
  const options: Partial<IClientOptions> = {
    will: {
      topic: 'hello',
      payload: JSON.stringify({ clientId: '1', username: 'sean' }),
      qos: 1,
      retain: true
    },
    port: 443,
    clientId: '1', 
    username: 'sean'
  };
const client = mqtt.connect(
  request.url,
  options);

console.log(client);

client.on('connect', function() {
  client.subscribe('hello', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
    }
  });
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('error', err);
  client.end()
});

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I boot up my webpage, I am receiving the following repeated error in the Chrome dev tools:

`WebSocket connection to <AWS IoT Url> failed:`

Usually, there is an actual error message displayed after the *'... failed:'* string. In the code, I am seeing a nop function that is logging the error. Just curious what errors usually cause the nop function to be called and how could I can begin testing why my url is failing to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that my AWS IoT IAM credentials were invalid so I was unable to properly connect to the cloud. If the developers have time, it would be useful if the connect function would notify that this might be the problem. The current functionality of displaying an empty error message made it difficult to actually debug the problem

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68399355/10403160 - This comment is right as well.

I have fixed this using this method!

My Issue was after the user is logged out. MQTT is still trying to reconnect with the subscriber even after the MQTT is disconnected and the client is cleared. So, what happens is credentials are null because the user is logged out and MQTT is trying to AutoReconnect. So this error throws.

_setUpMqttClient() is a function executed when MQTT is connected to the client.

```
void _setUpMqttClient() {
    _url = _prepareWebSocketUrl();
    _client = mqttsetup.setup(_url, _clientId);
    // Set the protocol to V3.1.1 for AWS IoT Core, if you fail to do this you will not receive a connect ack with the response code
    _client.setProtocolV311();
    _client.logging(on: _logging);
    _client.autoReconnect = true;
    _client.port = 443;
    _client.keepAlivePeriod = 30;
    _client.disconnectOnNoResponsePeriod = 1;
    _client.onDisconnected = awsInterface.onDisConnected;
    _client.onConnected = awsInterface.onConnected;
    _client.onSubscribed = awsInterface.onSubScribed;
    _client.onSubscribeFail = awsInterface.onSubscribeFail;
    _client.onUnsubscribed = awsInterface.onUnsubscribed;
    _client.onAutoReconnect = awsInterface.onAutoReconnect;
    _client.onAutoReconnected = awsInterface.onAutoReconnected;
    _client.resubscribeOnAutoReconnect = true;
    _client.connectionMessage =
        MqttConnectMessage().withClientIdentifier(_clientId).startClean();
  }

  String get clientId => _clientId;
```

stopAutoReconnect() call this at the time of logout user or you want to disable auto-reconnect.

```
  void stopAutoReconnect() {
    _client?.autoReconnect = false;
    _client?.resubscribeOnAutoReconnect = false;
  }
```

write this code on logout.

```
static Future<void> onLogOutTap() async {
    AwsMqttConnection.client.stopAutoReconnect();
    AwsMqttConnection.instance.disConnect();
    AwsMqttConnection.instance.clear();
}
```

**Note: Above code is written in dart**